# int function and str() function in file handling . i dont know where im going wrong

Tags: python, file-handling

Path for the two files that you will require for this task has been stored in variables file_path_1 and file_path_2

Call the function readfile() written in the previous task for file_path_1 & file_path_2 and store their message sentences in variables message_1 and message_2 respectively.

Print message_1 and message_2 to see what they contain.

Write a function fuse_msg() that :

Takes message_a and message_b as parameters

Implements integer(floor) division of message_a over message_b (Don't forget to make messages as int before applying floor division) and stores the quotient in a variable called quotient

Returns quotient in string format.

> [Note you can convert any variable 'a' to string using str(a)]
>   read_file() is already defined in another

```
message_1 = read_file(file_path_1)
message_2 = read_file(file_path_2)
print(message_1)
print(message_2)

def fuse_msg(message_a , message_b) :
    quotient =  int(message_b // message_a)
    return str(quotient)

secret_msg_1 = fuse_msg(message_1,message_2)
```

Comment: if message a and message b to the function are strings then you cant devide them by each other. Instead convert message B and message A to ints so they can devide. `quotient =  int(message_b) // int(message_a)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert message_b and message_a to int or float before division

```
message_1 = read_file(file_path_1)
message_2 = read_file(file_path_2)
print(message_1)
print(message_2)

def fuse_msg(message_a , message_b) :
    quotient =  int(message_b) // int(message_a)
    return str(quotient)

secret_msg_1 = fuse_msg(message_1,message_2)
```